# MathJax in iOS uiwebview displays white boxes

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mathjax

[image]

Hi All,

When using the mathjax library inside a webview on iOS we are getting the above boxes. Has anyone experienced simular problems or knows of a fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be WebKit's native MathML rendering, which calls on fonts that are not available by default, and so those characters are rendered as a blank box (the missing character symbol).  The stretchy delimiters are made up of several such characters, which is why you gets stacks of boxes.

Either MathJax isn't actually running (so the native MathML support is being used instead) or you have MathJax configured to use NativeMML instead.  You could add something like

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {alert("MathJax Complete")});
</script>
```

somewhere before your script that loads MathJax to see if MathJax is actually running.  If you get the alert, then MathJax is processing the page.  If not, then look for a problem with access to the MathJax files.